# How to implement gotoxy() using printf()

Tags: c, function, printf

Can someone please tell me how gotoxy() is implemented using printf()

```
void gotoxy(int x,int y) 
{ printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x); }
```

What are the things written inside printf() supposed to mean to the compiler ?

Comment: generating ANSI escape sequences on the terminal right?

Comment: I got this on quora.
I want to implement this on a gcc compiler

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html  The compiler doesn't have anything to do with it, key is that the OS terminal or console supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular `printf` is using char then integer formatting to generate an [ANSI escape sequence](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) (recognizable by ESC (aka `0x1B`) then `[`), then the coordinates to move cursor to. In your case:

> Esc[Line;Columnf  Cursor Position:
>
> Moves the cursor to the specified position (coordinates).
>   If you do not specify a position, the cursor moves to the home position at the upper-left corner of the screen (line 0, column 0).

When this sequence is issued to a capable terminal through standard output like `printf` does (not all terminals are compatible), the command is executed by the terminal, it's not compiler or compiler library dependent.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you came to know this ? Sources please

Comment: You can read book C Programming : A Modern Approach 2nd Edition, it will help you a lot.

Comment: Nice jean, Maybe you won't remember me , you had 30k something some month ago and now 60k, you will soon enter 100k club, good luck.

Comment: @GauravPant it's just that I recognized ANSI escape sequence in the intent of the function.

Comment: @SurajJain yeah I don't, but I wrote 2300+ answers so it's difficult to remember everyone. thanks for the support ("soon" could be changed to "soon enough" :))